# How to return a driven collection of [List<>] after filtering by [Where]?

Tags: c#, linq

In the following collection:

```
public class PersonsCollection : List<Person>
```

How can I return an instance of `PersonsCollection` after filtering by `Where` extension?

```
personCollections.Where(p => p.Name == "Jack").ToList(); 
// will return IEnumerable<Person>, How to return PersonsCollection?
```

Any idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You´d have to create a new instance of `PersonsCollection` instead, e.g.

```
return new PersonsCollection(personsCollection.Where(p => p.Name == "Jack"))
```

assuming you have an appropriate constructor.

Generally it´s a bad idea to extend the built-in collections anyway (rather than using composition) - are you sure you want this design in the first place?

Comment: @Jon, what happened to your keyboard :-)? `´` and `¨` are strange symbols.

Comment: @Darin: I´m on a Cr-48 which is doing odd things with quotes. Need to work out how to fix it...

Comment: @Jon, is this the notebook that was intro-ed in a Google video in which they smash at least 20 of them?

Comment: @Jon, I'm not sure if I need to derive from `List`. Acutally I converted this code from an old one was using `CollectionBase`, that's all.

Comment: @Darin: That´s the one. Other than the current keyboard handling (and lack of a C# compiler) it´s proving very nice.

Comment: @Jon: Seems no added value from deriving from `List`, using a new type with a collection as a member would be better, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Jack: Exactly. Favour composition over inheritance, generally. Of course there are exceptions to every rule...

Answer (score 0):

You could to create an Extension Method `ToList()` for an `IEnumerable<Person>`...

```
public static class PersonCollectionExtensions
{
    public static List<Person> ToList(this IEnumerable<Person> self)
    {
         return new PersonCollection(self);
    }
}
```

Comment: That´s going to be very confusing to anyone who´s used to LINQ to Objects. It would be more self-explanatory if you called it ToPersonsCollection (and changed the return type).

Comment: Isn't a `PersonCollection` a `List<Person>`? But I see what you mean. I was just trying to have his code work. Sure, it probably should be called `ToPersonsCollection()`.

Comment: Yes, it is - but do you really want to force the OP to cast whenever they call it and want to assign the value to a `PersonsCollection` variable? Given that the whole point of this over the normal `ToList` method is to create a different type, it seems pointless to ignore that when it comes to the return type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the proper constructor in your collection:

```
public class PersonsCollection : List<Person> {
  public PersonsCollection() { }
  public PersonsCollection(IEnumerable<Person> persons) : base(persons) { }
}
```

You can then filter it like this:

```
new PersonsCollection(personCollections.Where(p => p.Name == "Jack"));
```

From your comment about `CollectionBase` I guess that you are refactoring old code not using generics. [Krzysztof Cwalina](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/) made a blog post about [how to transition from non-generic collections to generic collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/09/23/collections.aspx). You may also find his comment on a blog post [why `List<T>` isn't recommended in public API's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/09/26/474010.aspx) interesting:

> We recommend using `Collection<T>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, or `KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem>` for outputs and properties and interfaces `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IList<T>` for inputs.

You could simply get rid of `PersonsCollection` and use something like `Collection<Person>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var pc = new PersonCollection();
pc.AddRange(personCollections.Where(p => p.Name == "Jack").ToArray());
return pc;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities:

1. Your PersonsCollection has a constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<Person>`, so you create a new PersonsCollection based on the query result.
2. You can create a new extension method ToPersonsCollection() that constructs the PersonsCollection (may be combined with the above.)
3. You can change your dependencies so that other code doesn't require a PersonsCollection and can instead work with `IEnumerable<Person>` (this is the option that I'd recommend.)